# AttributeError: module 'pims' has no attribute 'AVVideoReader'

Tags: python, video-processing, avif, pyav

Trying to read an avi file with pims and it shows `AttributeError: module 'pims' has no attribute 'AVVideoReader'`

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import av
import pims
import trackpy as tp
import os

import matplotlib  as mpl 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
my_avi_img = pims.AVVideoReader('/content/WideCam.avi')
```

Comment: [mre] is required. also take the [tour]

Comment: Replace `pims.AVVideoReader` with `pims.PyAVVideoReader`. See the [documentation](http://soft-matter.github.io/pims/v0.6.1/video.html).